# For structure not working properly, not printing the phrase after a non prime number

Tags: c, for-loop, scope, primes

So, im developing an algorithm that shows if a number is a prime number or not. But when i type the first non prime number, it stops recognizing what is a prime number (or at least stops printing, idk). pls help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int num, i, p, soma=0;

    //Repeticao para o algoritmo todo
    for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
        printf("\nDigite o %do numero: \n",i);
        scanf("%i", &num);
        //Decobrir se eh primo ou nao
        for(p = 2; p <= num / 2; p++) {
            if(num % p==0){
                soma++;
            }
        }
        //saida
        if (soma == 0){
            printf("%d eh um numero primo!", num);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You need to reset `soma` to `0`. `if (soma == 0) { printf("%d eh um numero primo!", num); } else { soma = 0; }`

Comment: Incidentally, declare `main` as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 2):

You never reset `soma` to zero. The first time a factor is found, `soma` is incremented. Forever after that, it is non-zero, so the test in `if (soma == 0)` is never true.

You should reset `soma` to zero for each new number to be tested.

One method to help avoid mistakes like this is not to declare variables before you need them:

```
// You do not need any of these here:
//    int num, i, p, soma=0;

// You can declare i here:
    //Repeticao para o algoritmo todo
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
// You need num here:
        int num;
        printf("\nDigite o %do numero: \n",i);
        scanf("%i", &num);
        //Decobrir se eh primo ou nao
// Now you need soma:
        int soma = 0;
// You need p here:
        for(int p = 2; p <= num / 2; p++) {
            if(num % p==0){
                soma++;
            }
        }
        //saida
        if (soma == 0){
            printf("%d eh um numero primo!", num);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At least the variable `soma` must be declared within the outer for loop before the inner for loop

```
//Repeticao para o algoritmo todo
for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
    int soma = 0;
```

But in any case the approach is incorrect because if the user will enter `0` or `1` (that are not prime numbers) your program will say that it is a prime number. Also It is evident that any even number except `2` is not a prime number.

Also declare variables where they are used. And the variable `num` should be declared as having the type `unsigned int`.

I would rewrite the loops the following way

```
//Repeticao para o algoritmo todo
for( int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    unsigned int num;

    printf("\nDigite o %do numero: \n",i);
    scanf("%u", &num);

    int soma = num % 2 == 0 ? num == 2 : num != 1;

    //Decobrir se eh primo ou nao
    for( unsigned int p = 2; soma &&  p <= num / p; p++) {
        if(num % p==0) soma = 0;
    }
    //saida
    if ( soma ){
        printf("%d eh um numero primo!", num);
    }
}
```